# Error loading shared libraries of boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-libraries

I am working on centos. I installed boost version 1.45.0 on my system. The programs are compiled correctly but whenever I type command to see output it gives following error:

> ./a.out: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libboost_thread.so.1.45.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How did you install the boost libraries?

The problem you're likely having is that the linker can not find the libraries, and when you built your program, you had to manually specify additional library paths to search for libraries.

A quick fix you can do is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory where the boost thread library is:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

`./runExecutable`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, you can also set the `DT_RPATH` elf tag when linking your executable

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/boost/libraries -L /path/to/boost/libraries -lboost_whatever
```

This way you don't have to remember to set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if the libraries are installed in a non-standard location.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include the path to the Boost libraries (they're possibly in `/usr/local/lib`, etc).

In bash, this is simply

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: in tcsh it is setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /path/to/boost:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH