# caffe can't find libboost_system.so.166.0

Tags: boost, shared-libraries, caffe

I'm installing caffe on an Ubuntu 17.04 system using boost 1.66. I am able to execute `make all` and `make test` without problems:

```
me@icvr1:~/PackageDownloads/caffe$ make all
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
me@icvr1:~/PackageDownloads/caffe$ make test
make: Nothing to be done for 'test'.
```

However, when I try `make runtest`, I get the following error:

```
me@icvr1:~/PackageDownloads/caffe$ make runtest
.build_release/tools/caffe
.build_release/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:532: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Error 127
```

Now, I know that `libboost_system.so.1.66.0` exists in `/usr/local/lib`, which (I believe) is a fairly standard location:

```
me@icvr1:~/PackageDownloads/caffe$ ls /usr/local/lib/libboost_system*
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a  /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so  /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.66.0
```

and, in caffe's `Makefile.config`, `/usr/local/lib` is on the library path:

```
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

So, what am I missing here? How can I ensure `caffe` will know where to find `libboost_system.so.1.66.0` ?

Comment: This should help you to solve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581305/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libboost-system-so-1-45-0-cannot-open-sha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.66.0` is evidently one you built
yourself and want the loader to find at runtime without special measures.

But having built it, you didn't update the [ldconfig](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) cache
(because you didn't know you had to); so the runtime loader is not yet aware that this
library exists and can't find it.

When the loader is looking for the shared libraries needed to assemble a new process,
it does not search all of the linker's default search directories. That would be slow.
By default it searches a cached database `/etc/ld.so.cache`, of libraries that were
found by `ldconfig`, last time it was run.

By default, `ldconfig` caches libraries that it finds in `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and in the directrories
listed in the file `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and/or any similar `*.conf` files that are recursively `include`-ed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.
For example:

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf

$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/nvidia-384
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384
/usr/lib/nvidia-384
/usr/lib32/nvidia-384
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/lib32
/usr/lib32
```

You see that `/usr/local/lib` is listed there. So, to make the loader aware
of your new `/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.66.0`, just run:

```
ldconfig
```

as root. You need to do likewise anytime you install a new locally built
shared library in `/usr/local/lib`.

If you want the loader to find a shared library `/a/b/libfoo.so` that isn't in the `ldconfig`
cache, you can get it to do so by the special measure of appending `/a/b/libfoo.so` to the value of the
environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which by default is empty) in the environment in which you launch
the process that needs to load that library. The loader will search the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
directories, if any, before the `ldconfig` cache. However, *not* adding a shared library
to the `ldconfig` cache should be an informed choice and setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
is, of course, not well motivated merely by ignorance of the `ldconfig` apparatus or of the linker's [`-rpath` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Options.html)