# A simpler method to load shared libraries without root

Tags: c++, boost, linker, g++

I am trying to compile and run a C++ program on a server where I don't have root access. I am having trouble linking`boost_iostreams` library.

I can successfully compile my program by pointing to the boost installation directory using the `-L` flag as: 
 `g++ -I path/to/boost/build/include -o out prog1.cpp prog2.cpp  -L path/to/boost/build/lib -lboost_iostreams`

However, if I run the program as `./out` I get the error `error while loading shared libraries: libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` since the linker is not able to locate `libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0` (which DOES exist under `path/to/boost/build/lib`)

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581396/937153) answer, I was able to explicitly specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and run the program as

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path/to/boost/build/lib" ./out`.

Since I am not root, I can't run `ldconfig` either. I was wondering if there is a way to load dynamic libraries without having to prefix `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when you run the program and no root access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve this using the method explained here https://amir.rachum.com/blog/2016/09/17/shared-libraries/. The solution is to use `rpath` during compilation.

> According to the article  The only difference between `rpath` and
>   `runpath` is the order they are searched in. Specifically, their
>   relation to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` - `rpath` is searched in before
>   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` while `runpath` is searched in after. The meaning of
>   this is that `rpath` cannot be changed dynamically with environment
>   variables while `runpath` can.

In short once you compile with `-rpath path/to/boost/build/lib`, the directory containing the library `libboost_iostreams.so.1.67.0` is searched at runtime without having to prefix `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path/to/boost/build/lib" ./out`.

After compiling with 
`g++ -I path/to/boost/build/include -o out prog1.cpp prog2.cpp  -L path/to/boost/build/lib -lboost_iostreams -rpath path/to/boost/build/lib`

I was able to run `./out` without any issues.

**EDIT 1**

As pointed by Nikos in the comments, alternatively you can set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/boost/build/lib`. Add this line to `.~/.bashrc` file so that it is not lost when you log out.

Comment: You can just add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/boost/build/lib` in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @NikosC. Oh, that was a lot easier. I made a rookie mistake and didn't use `export` and tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path/to/boost/build/lib` which didn't work. I will keep the answer here regardless as an alternate method of pointing to runtime shared libraries.