# Issue executing boost binary

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries

I'm trying to setup an environment for my next project (which surprise surprise, involves boost) and have ran into an issue. As a bit of background, the c++ compiler and boost have been built from source. Anyways, here is the issue:

```
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$ type g++-5.3.0 
g++-5.3.0 is aliased to `g++-5.3.0 -I/home/nchambers/mini-bin/.binaries/boost_1_60_0/include -L/home/nchambers/mini-bin/.binaries/boost_1_60_0/lib'
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$ cat test.cpp 
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$ g++-5.3.0 -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -w test.cpp -o boosttest -lboost_system -lboost_regex
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$ ./boosttest 
./boosttest: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.60.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$ [[ -f mini-bin/.binaries/boost_1_60_0/lib/libboost_system.so.1.60.0 ]] && echo 'file exists'
file exists
nchambers@nchambers-305E4A-305E5A-305E7A:~$
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think this question( http://stackoverflow.com/q/4250624/2417774 ) may help.

Comment: @cv_and_he: Good find, looks like a duplicate. DTSCode: is there any difference, or should we close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @MSalters [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568187/error-loading-shared-libraries-of-boost) is probably a better duplicate.

Comment: True, and it's not Boost specific so there are dozens of other duplicates.

Comment: Yes it is indeed a duplicate :) thanks guys!