# python `ImportError: libboost_python27.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory `

Tags: python, boost, anaconda

I'm running into a problem using a boost-compiled c++ code for python2. I've gotten this to install correctly using the boost package for anaconda2-2019 on WSL, but importing the python package yields the error:

```
ImportError: libboost_python27.so.1.67.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found where the `libboost_python27.so.1.67.0` lives in `~/anaconda2/lib/` so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but you could try the following solutions taken from similar problem at [Error loading shared libraries of boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568187/error-loading-shared-libraries-of-boost)

1. link the c++ code module with the following flag

```
-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/boost/libraries -lboost_python
```

2. export the lib folder where the missing library is located

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/boost/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```